# Is there a way to define the relationship type using a dataframe column in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, types, neo4j, databricks, relationship

Is there a way to define the relationship type using a dataframe column in spark?

```
import pandas as pd

_list = []
_dict = {}

_dict['ENV'] = "DEV"
_dict['PRIVILEGE'] = "DML"
_dict['ROLE'] = "ROLE1"
_dict['DATABASE'] = "Database1"
_list.append(_dict)

_dict['ENV'] = "DEV"
_dict['PRIVILEGE'] = "DDL"
_dict['ROLE'] = "ROLE2"
_dict['DATABASE'] = "Database1"
_list.append(_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(_list)
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df.write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource") \
  .mode("Overwrite")  \
  .option("relationship", df["PRIVILEGE"]) \
  .option("relationship.save.strategy", "keys") \
  .option("relationship.target.labels", "DATABASE") \
  .option("relationship.target.node.keys", "DATABASE, ENV") \
  .option("relationship.target.save.mode", "overwrite") \
  .option("relationship.source.labels", "ROLE") \
  .option("relationship.source.save.mode", "overwrite") \
  .option("relationship.source.node.keys", "ROLE, ENV") \
  .save()
```

It is writing the type as Column<'PRIVILEGE'>, when I want the value.

Comment: You can do a loop per distinct value of column <priv> then pass it to the write command as a string.

Comment: too many rows to employ any iterator. I thought of a few ways to iterate, but end up with a lot of code and much slower executions. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do raise an issue so the team can consider how it can be implemented

The approaches i've seen be used are to either:

- **iterate one relationship type at a time** (as mentioned by @cybersam and @jose_bacoy)

e.g. get unique values of the PRIVILEGE column = relationship types

```
relTypeColumn="PRIVILEGE"
uniquerelTypes=df.dropDuplicates([relTypeColumn])
relTypes = uniquerelTypes.select(relTypeColumn).collect()
```

Then iterate over those relationship types, filter the DataFrame for those rows that match and write to Neo4j

```
for row in relTypes:
    relType=row[relTypeColumn]
    relsubset=df.filter(df[relTypeColumn] == relType)
    relsubset.write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource") \
    .mode("Overwrite")  \
    .option("relationship", relType) \
    .option("relationship.save.strategy", "keys") \
    .option("relationship.target.labels", "DATABASE") \
    .option("relationship.target.node.keys", "DATABASE, ENV") \
    .option("relationship.target.save.mode", "overwrite") \
    .option("relationship.source.labels", "ROLE") \
    .option("relationship.source.save.mode", "overwrite") \
    .option("relationship.source.node.keys", "ROLE, ENV") \
    .option("url", neo4j_url) \
    .option("authentication.type", "basic") \
    .option("authentication.basic.username", neo4j_user) \
    .option("authentication.basic.password", neo4j_password) \
    .save()
```

- **use [apoc.create.relationship](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.relationship/) or [apoc.merge.relationship](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.relationship/) within a `query`**

e.g. write nodes

```
df.write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource") \
.mode("Overwrite")  \
.option("labels", ":DATABASE") \
.option("node.keys", "DATABASE,ENV") \
.option("schema.optimization.type", "NODE_CONSTRAINTS") \
.option("url", neo4j_url) \
.option("authentication.type", "basic") \
.option("authentication.basic.username", neo4j_user) \
.option("authentication.basic.password", neo4j_password) \
.save()
```

Then write the relationships using apoc to allow passing in dynamic values from the DataFrame

```
df.write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource") \
.mode("Overwrite")  \
.option("query", """
MATCH (database:DATABASE {DATABASE:event.DATABASE, ENV:event.ENV}) 
MATCH (role:ROLE {ROLE:event.ROLE, ENV:event.ENV})
WITH database, role, event
CALL apoc.create.relationship(database, event.PRIVILEGE, {}, role) YIELD rel
return count(role)""") \
.option("url", neo4j_url) \
.option("authentication.type", "basic") \
.option("authentication.basic.username", neo4j_user) \
.option("authentication.basic.password", neo4j_password) \
.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

`df["PRIVILEGE"]` returns a `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`, so what you are using as the relationship type is just the value of `Column.toString()` (i.e., `Column<'PRIVILEGE'>`).

The "relationship" `option` expects its argument (the relationship type) to be a fixed string. It does not support getting the relationship type name dynamically from a `DataFrame` column.

Therefore, you should create a separate `DataFrame` for each relationship type and have a separate `write` for each `DataFrame`.

And, by the way, since you reuse the same `_dict` instance for every `_list` element, all `_list` elements will be identical. You need to create a new dict for every element.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I chose to just change my model and have privilege become a node instead of a relationship. I don't understand the constraint given the ability to use df values within the keys options. Feels like something that should have been allowed. oh well.

Comment: @PythonNoob please create an issue: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/issues/new